# How to change an event's sender in WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

I want to set the sender of an event to something other than the actual initiator of the event. Consider this simple DataTemplate for my CImage class:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type er:CImage}">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" MaxWidth="{Binding Image.Width}">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" MouseUp="MouseUpHandler" />
            <Label Content="{Binding ImageFile.Name}" />
            <Label>
                <TextBlock  TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding TagsJoined}" />
            </Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When the user clicks on this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" MouseUp="MouseUpHandler" />
```

The "MouseUpHandler" event handler needs access to the "CImage" object of which "ImageSource" is a property, not the "Image" object to which "ImageSource" has been bound.

Is there any way to communicate this information in the event itself or do I have no choice but to have the handler look up the CImage through other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sender will always be Image object, that you can't change.**

However, in handler you can access `DataContext` of `Image` which will be object of `CImage` since DataType of DataTemplate is CImage:

```
private void MouseUpHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    CImage instance = (CImage)((Image)sender).DataContext;
}
```

Comment: This should work. I've had a similar issue and the important thing to note is you need to cast the sender to fit your needs. So in the above example he casts sender as an Image and then as a CImage. Finally you'll be able to access the DataContext property.